# Clear all bits set in a pilosa field at once

Tags: go, pilosa

Is there any method in Go to clear all bits set in a pilosa field at once? I checked this link [go-pilosa](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pilosa/go-pilosa), but it has a method for clearing each row in a field. I need to clear all rows in a particular field.

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: Would deleting and recreating the field be viable for you?

Comment: @monguin that is my last option

Answer (score 0):

you can always remove the field and recreate it